# Serialize and deserialize singles values in JSON.NET C#?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I use VS 2012, .NET 3.5, JSON.NET.
I have several single values likes int, string types.
I set string value with `~ separator`.
I serialize the string, save it in a file.
Then, I deserialize the string from the file and I Split string.

I want avoid Split by `~ character` and I want avoid create a new type (class entity with properties get;set ).

I think using Anonymous types or Dynamic is complex.

Any suggestions?

Unit test working now:

```
    var value1 = "C20100101_0001";
    var value2 = 678901;
    var value3 = "lorem ipsum text %&/() more test";
    var value4 = "email@gmail.com";
    string json = "{0}~{1}~{2}~{3}".FormatString(value1, value2, value3, value4);
    var ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
    ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Formatting.Indented);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@".\path.txt", ser);

    var deser = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@".\path.txt");
    var json2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(deser);
    Assert.AreEqual(json, json2);

    var data = json2.Split(new char[] { '~' });
    Assert.IsNotNull(data);
    Assert.AreNotEqual(0, data.Length);
    Assert.AreEqual(value1, data[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you could just dump everything in an array and serialize that:

```
var list = new object[]{"C20100101_0001", 678901, "lorem ipsum text %&/() more test", "email@gmail.com"};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[]>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

With @EagleEak answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28325833/206730, a solution in unit test working:

```
        var value1 = "C20100101_0001";
        var value2 = 678901;
        var value3 = "lorem ipsum text %&/() more test";
        var value4 = "email@gmail.com";
        var list = new object[] { value1, value2, value3, value4 };
        ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.Indented);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@".\path.txt", ser);

        deser = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@".\path.txt");
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[]>(deser);
        Assert.IsNotNull(deserialized);
        Assert.AreNotEqual(0, deserialized.Length);
        Assert.AreEqual(value1, deserialized[0]);
```